# Why is JQuery UI sortable not dropping if I modify variables outside of its scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following piece of code.
See the two comments for the problem.

```
$(settings.columns).sortable({
  ...
  ...
  start: function(e, ui) {
    ...
    stickies.block = true; // This line is OK
  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    ...
    stickies.block = false; // Without this line it works, with it I can't drop the widget
  }
});
```

By can't drop, I mean I can pick it up fine but letting go of the mouse button doesn't work and I am still holding the widget.
Any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reproduce the issue on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I worked it out. I was accidentally returning false as CoffeeScript makes the last line of a statement return so I had this.

```
$(settings.columns).sortable({
  ...
  ...
  start: function(e, ui) {
    ...
    return stickies.block = true; // This line is OK
  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    ...
    return stickies.block = false; // Without this line it works, with it I can't drop the widget
  }
});
```

Of course, the returning false cancelled the event and stopped it from dropping the note.